# How to change textview of custom listview on clicking-android

Tags: android

I did an android application which has custom `listview` with checkbox & text per line.Now i want to change text color on clicking of both text or checkbox if any.How could i do this?

My Code:

```
String[] planets = new String[] { "Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars",
        "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune" };
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    LSOne = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    planetList.addAll(Arrays.asList(planets));
    // Create ArrayAdapter using the planet list.
    LsAdapter listAdapter = new LsAdapter(this, R.layout.country_info,
            planetList);
    LSOne.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    LSOne.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1,
                int position, long id) {        
        }
    });
}
public class LsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private String[] mTaxi = null;
    private String[] mid = null;
    long id;
    public static final boolean isEnabled = true;
    private int mViewResourceId;
    public LsAdapter(Context ctx, int viewResourceId,
            ArrayList<String> planetList) {
        super(ctx, viewResourceId);
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        String[] tax = planetList.toArray(new String[planetList.size()]);
        mTaxi = tax;
        mViewResourceId = viewResourceId;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mTaxi.length;
    }
    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return mTaxi[position];
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 20;
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));
        int _intPosition = getItemViewType(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.country_info, null);
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.code = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    holder.name = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
    convertView.setTag(holder);
    holder.code.setText(mTaxi[position]);
    holder.name.setId(_intPosition);
    if (flag == 1) {
    holder.name.setEnabled(false);
    } else if (flag == 0) {
    holder.name.setEnabled(true);
}
    holder.name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (int i = 0; i < _intRadio.length; i++) {
            if (i == v.getId()) {
            _intRadio[i] = 1;
        } else {
            _intRadio[i] = 0;
        }
    }
            holder.code.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
holder.code.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        holder.code.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
        // v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        if (_intRadio[_intPosition] == 1) {
            holder.name.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            holder.name.setChecked(false);
        }
        return convertView;
    }
    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView code;
        RadioButton name;
        Button btn;
    }
}}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        if (row == null) {
            // ROW INFLATION
            Log.d("ExamAdapter", "Starting XML Row Inflation ... ");

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_gold, parent, false);
            Log.d("ExamAdapter", "Successfully completed XML Row Inflation!");
        }

        // Get item
        Gold text = getItem(position);
        subject = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        time = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        String content = text.content;

        String times = text.time;

        subject.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                subject.setBackgroundColor(R.color.red_color);
            }
        });



        /* String[] com = content.split(Pattern.quote("*")); */

        subject.setText(content.replace("*", "\n"));

        return row;
    }
```

Try This code..

Write **subject.setBackgroundColor(R.color.red_color);** this line inside the onClick listener...

Answer (score 0):

Before `notifyDataSetChanged();` in ur code, get the position and store it in a static variable. And before `return convertView;` check the position with the static variable and try `holder.name.setBackgroundColor(<color>)` . I think it ll work.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your onClick listener... try like this

> ```
>      holder.name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
> ```

Hope this will work